# how to avoid program termination when exception occur in java

Tags: java, android

I am doing an app for finding BPM in Android.  Based on the input of the file null pointer exception and IO exception is getting thrown.  When the exception occurs the program is terminated, even if I surround the code with a try/catch block.  My requirement is that the program not terminate, and continue to the other parts.

**My Code:**

```
try {
    mp3file.seekMP3Frame();
    sourcefile = new File("/sdcard/a.mp3");
    mp3file = new MP3File(sourcefile);
    AbstractID3v2 tag = mp3file.getID3v2Tag();
    text=tag.getFrame("TBPM").toString();       
} 
catch (NullPointerException e) {
    System.out.println("null pointer exception");
}
catch (IOException e1) {
    System.out.println("IO exception");
}
........  // other coding
```

Comment: You have sure that the exception is thouwn by this code? Try enable a Exception Break on your Exception codename on Debug view.

Comment: Are you sure about getting exception out of these two only? add 1 more catch block for common Exception

Comment: `NullPointerException`s are generally triggered by logical errors rather than unpredictable conditions. You may want to check what throws them and fix it rather than catch it.

Comment: Fishy. Do you see the print lines? Could you possibly have a different error being thrown? You can try to catch a Throwable (parent interface of both Exception and Error) and see if you land in that block...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use `finally` block in your code which is like

```
 `try{

 } catch{

 } finally{

 }`
```

finally will execute even if your try block throws exception or even if it doesn't.

Comment: If a runtime exception occurs between the try catch block, the app will still crash. Only way to avoid this is to catch ALL exceptions (using java.lang.Throwable). Obviously, this doesn't take into account Errors (ex: NoClassDefFoundError)

Comment: The finally block would be executed even if the code throws a runtime exception, but that exception would be propagated after the finally block has been executed, and the app could then terminate. This does not solve the problem.

Comment: This answer is not solving the issue. You need to understand the concept of multiple catch. To make sure that all error being catched, you should catch(Throwable th) in the very last end of the catch. Finally just mean that even you have exceptio/dont have exception you still want to do something similar inside the finally block. For example, close connection.

Answer (score 1):

- If the error occurs between the try - catch block :

You are only catching 2 exceptions here (NullPointerException  and IOException).
Any other runtime exception between the try - catch block can still cause your program to crash.  catch java.lang.Throwable to ensure all exceptions are catched.

- If the error doesn't occur between the try - catch block :

Look in the stacktrace for the line in your class where the error occurs, and implement "proper" error handling there.

If your application crashes, you'll always see a stacktrace in logcat. That stacktrace will be able to tell you what line of code is causing the crash.